# jQuery hover 2 elements

Tags: jquery

I have 2 elements: `initiator` and `receptor`.

On mouseenter or hovering `initiator`, I want the `receptor` to be active and remain active only if I'm moving mouse inside of `receptor`. If I'm moving the mouse outside of `initiator` & `receptor`, I want `receptor` to be inactive.

This is what I tried but is not the result I want.

```js
$(function () {
    var initiator = $("#initiator");
  var receptor = $(".receptor");

  initiator.on("mouseenter", function () {
    receptor.addClass('active');
  });
  
  receptor.on("mouseleave", function () {
    receptor.removeClass('active');
  }); 
});
```

```css
#initiator {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.receptor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="initiator"> </div>
<div class="receptor"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost there. The change you need to make is that the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events needs to be bound to both `initiator` and `receptor`. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  var $initiator = $("#initiator");
  var $receptor = $(".receptor");

  $initiator.add($receptor).on({
    mouseenter: () => $receptor.addClass('active'),
    mouseleave: () => $receptor.removeClass('active')
  });
});
```

```css
#initiator {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.receptor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="initiator"> </div>
<div class="receptor"> </div>
```

An alternative, slightly more reliable, approach would be to wrap both the `initiator` and `receptor` in a parent container and attach the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to that only. This way you avoid any issues where the `mousenter` event can be fired when moving the mouse slowly between the elements, or if there is a gap between them.

Comment: Yep, It's working. Thank you @Rory McCrossan

Comment: No problem, glad to help